# По каким параметрам сокета можно определить, что TCP-соединение установлено?

Tags: c++, tcp, connect

Создаю TCP-сокет, делаю неблокирующим, ассоциирую с `epoll_event`, добавляю в `epoll` и вызываю `connect`. Если `connect` возвращиет `EWOULDBLOCK`, навешиваю коллбек на `EPOLLOUT`, в котором хочу определить когда сокет будет готов для работы и снять `EPOLLOUT`, чтобы больше не триггерился на запись.

Как определить что соединение готово (или завершилось с ошибкой)?

Comment: Будет вызван навешанный коллбек.

Comment: @user7860670, изначально тоже так думал, но проверил - нет. ```EPOLLOUT``` будет срабатывать на любом сокете с валидным дескриптором, даже если никаких сетевых операций на нём ещё не выполнялось. Это просто означает возможность записывать по этому дескриптору.

Comment: Так по TCP сокету есть возможность записывать когда соединение установлено.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
socklen_t err_len;
int error;
err_len = sizeof(error);
if(getsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &error, &err_len) < 0 || error != 0) {
    ошибка соединения error
} else {
    соединились !
}
```